# C++ .ignore gives error "This declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Tags: c++, c

I was trying to write a code to readfile from txt file (Its not complete yet). But the code showing an error in .ignore function. Error: `This declaration has no storage class or type specifier` can someone help me whats wrong here? The following is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//ifstream inFile;
//ofstream outfile;

//inFile.open("\.\Assignment01", ios::in);
//inFile.ignore(500, '\n');
ifstream input_file;
ifstream input_file("Course_of_sales.txt");
input_file.ignore(500, '\n');
ofstream output_file("output.txt");

string Record;

string day, month, year, hr, mins, secs, PM_AM, condetion;
double price , value;
int volume;

while (getline(inFile, record, ',')){
    day = record.substr(0,2);
    month = record.substr(3,2);
    year = record.substr(6,4);
}
```

Comment: You need to put your code in a function.

Comment: You can't put statements outside of functions, only declarations and definitions.

Comment: Oh yes. It worked. I just declared my function. Thanks a lot friends

Answer (score 1):

need to put code in a function. Thanks to Neil.